# TimescaleDB on Azure Postgres error when creating continuous aggregation

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, timescaledb

I am getting the following error

```
SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: functionality not supported under the current license "ApacheOnly", license¶  Hint: Upgrade to a Timescale-licensed binary to access this free community feature
```

when running the following:

```
CREATE VIEW test.weather_metrics_daily
WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
AS
SELECT
   time_bucket('1 day', time) as bucket,
   city_name,
   avg(temp_c) as avg_temp,
   avg(feels_like_c) as feels_like_temp,
   max(temp_c) as max_temp,
   min(temp_c) as min_temp,
   avg(pressure_hpa) as pressure,
   avg(humidity_percent) as humidity_percent,
   avg(rain_3h_mm) as rain_3h,
   avg(snow_3h_mm) as snow_3h,
   avg(wind_speed_ms) as wind_speed,
   avg(clouds_percent) as clouds
FROM
 test.weather_metrics
GROUP BY bucket, city_name;
```

I am using Azure Database for PostgreSQL server with Timescaledb enabled.

```
SELECT default_version, installed_version FROM pg_available_extensions
where name = 'timescaledb';

I get the version 1.7.4 on both
```

I am following the getting started document:
https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/getting-started/

Is this because of Azure Database for PostgreSQL server not having all functionalities or something else?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Check out Timescale licenses: https://www.timescale.com/legal/licenses/

Probably the latest redistributed version that is shipped in Azure is not compatible.

Comment: This question was also asked in another stack exchange site (https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/298765/185681) and was answered there: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/298779/185681

Comment: thanks guys. I will close this one here since I got an answer on dba stack exange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by [Мелкий](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10983392/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)  on https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/298765/185681

This is because Azure is a cloud service and thus can not offer the free "community" license of TimescaleDB. Per TimescaleDB FAQ:

> TimescaleDB is a relational database for time-series, with some
> features licensed under the Apache 2.0 License but many of the
> features you know and love are licensed via the Timescale License
> (including continuous aggregates, compression, data retention
> policies, actions, multi-node, and more). The "Apache 2.0" version of
> TimescaleDB offered by Microsoft, Digital Ocean, and others includes
> only the features in the Apache license. The Timescale License
> prohibits cloud providers from offering the "community version" of
> TimescaleDB-as-a-service.

Comment: Just to add that TimescaleDB Community version is available on AWS, GCP, and Azure if you use Timescale managed services. (Disclosure: I work for Timescale).